# USB Camera is detected but not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, usb, camera

I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and 18.04 multibooting.
In 20.04, usb cam is detected and working.
But In 18.04 usb cam is detected but not working

$> lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
**Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:08e5 Logitech, Inc.** 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0751 Genesys Logic, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0557:2419 ATEN International Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0557:7000 ATEN International Co., Ltd Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Device 004: ID 046d:08e5 is Logitech c920 HD webcam. As you can see, webcam is detected.

But when I try `cheese`. It says "No device found".

```
$ ls /dev/video*
ls: cannot access '/dev/video*': No such file or directory
```

Please help me sombody. I spent two days on this.

Comment: It maybe because 18.04 has an older kernel which does not support this webcam. Can you try upgrading your kernel to 5.13 using a tool like https://github.com/bkw777/mainline (Please note that there are risks involved with upgrading your kernel. Don't do it if you don't know how to revert back).

Comment: Also, 18.04 is quite an old version. Is there any specific reason you still need it? Consider upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I am using 18.04 for isaac sdk. It just works on 18.04. I will try to update kernel 5.13 as you recommend. Thanks.